# i don`t understand where is the memoery leak

Tags: c, cs50

i am trying to solve speller , and i did well with the logic but i have some memory leaks and i dont understand where it came from

here is my implemented functions

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

node *hashtable[N];
    unsigned int words = 0;
    // Hashes word to a number between 0 and 25, inclusive, based on its first letter
    unsigned int hash(const char *word)
    {
        return tolower(word[0]) - 'a';
    }

    // Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
    bool load(const char *dictionary)
    {
        // Initialize hash table
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            hashtable[i] = NULL;
        }

        // Open dictionary
        FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }

        // Buffer for a word
        char word[LENGTH + 1];

        // Insert words into hash table


        while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
        {
            node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

            if (!new_node)
            {
                unload();
                return false;
            }

            strcpy(new_node -> word, word);
            int x = hash(new_node -> word);
            if (hashtable[x] == NULL)
            {
                hashtable[x] = new_node;
                hashtable[x] -> next = NULL;

            }
            else
            {
                hashtable[x] -> next = new_node;
                new_node = hashtable[x];
            }

            words ++;
        }

        // Close dictionary
        fclose(file);
        // Indicate success
        return true;
    }

    // Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
    unsigned int size(void)
    {
        if (words > 0)
        {
            return words;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
    bool check(const char *word)
    {


        int k = hash(word);

        if (hashtable[k] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            for (node *ptr = hashtable[k]; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr -> next)
            {
                if (strcasecmp(ptr -> word, word) == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
    bool unload(void)
    {
        int index = 0;

        // iterate through entire hashtable array
        while (index < N)
        {
            // if hashtable is empty at index, go to next index
            if (hashtable[index] == NULL)
            {
                index++;
            }

            // if hashtable is not empty, iterate through nodes and start freeing
            else
            {
                while (hashtable[index] != NULL)
                {
                    node *cursor = hashtable[index];
                    hashtable[index] = cursor->next;
                    free(cursor);
                }

                // once hashtable is empty at index, go to next index
                index++;
            }
        }

        // return true if successful
        return true;
    }
```

and that`s the result of help50 valgrind 
Looks like your program leaked 8,010,184 bytes of memory. Did you forget to free memory that you allocated via malloc? Take a closer look at line 56 of dictionary.c.

line 56 is `node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));`

thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't immediately see a leak, but I do see you freeing memory that still needs to be alive. Assignment between pointers doesn't copy the memory the pointers are pointing to, which means `hashtable[x] = new_node` followed by `free(new_node)` will make the `hashtable[x]` pointer invalid.

Comment: Please show definition of `node`.

Comment: `hashtable[x] -> next = new_node;` is not enough. You must go the end of the list to add the new node.

Comment: Beyond freeing a node you shoudn't be, the chaining is wrong, To add to a collision chain that already exists you should set the new node's `next` to to `hashtable[x]`, then `hashtable[x]` to the new node pointer. I.e. `new_node->next = hashtable[x]`, then `hashtable[x] = new_node;`. You're doing it backward, and never setting `new_node->next`. What I'm describing also means you don't have to special-case an empty collision chain.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie And that's very likely the source of the leak. The OP break the list losing previously nodes in it.

Comment: @YosefHesham I think you need to take a step back and (re)learn about linked lists before you try on hash-tables.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  i learned alot about linked list and i noticed the problem right now but thanks anyways

Comment: @WhozCraig i don`t know how i made this mistake ! i didn`t notice it , thx alot mate !

Comment: @WhozCraig i realized that whenn i say ` hashtable -> next ` , iam actually losing the list and so it won`t be totally freed , thanks very much man :)